# Regex Validation YYYYMMDD

Tags: html, regex, forms

So I need a bit of regex for validation in an input in a form.
I believe you can put regex patterns direct into HTML now? (How do I do this?)

I found this, but I'm not sure whether it is what I want?

```
"(((\\d\\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|([02468][048]|[13579][26])(00))(02)([012]\\d))|(\\d\\d([02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789])(02)([01]\\d|2[012345678]))|(\\d\\d\\d\\d((0[13578]|1[02])([012]\\d|3[01])|((0[46]|11)([012]\\d|30))))"
```

So, first bit:

4 digits, less than x (2017) (Needs to easily changeable?)

second bit:

2 digits, between 01 and 12

third bit:

2 digits, between 01 and 31 (I don't care for per month changes)

Comment: To use your RegEx in your HTML form you have to add `pattern="[A-Za-z]{12}"` as attribute to your input field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this should do it:

`(201[0-7]|200[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{3})(1[0-2]|0[1-9])(3[01]|[0-2][1-9]|[12]0)`

Here's an example on [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3drkf).

## Breakdown:

**`(201[0-7]|200[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{3})` matches either:**

- 201 followed by a digit between 0 and 7 (2010..2017)
- *or* 200 followed by a digit between 0 and 9 (2000..2009)
- *or* a zero or a one, followed by three digits between 0 and 9 (0000..1999). If you do not wish to show years under 1000, you could simply do `(201[0-7]|200[0-9]|1[0-9]{3})`.

*Note: If you wanna match something over 2020, you can change this segment to `(202[0-7]|20[01][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{3})`, allowing anything from 0000..2027*

**The next segment, `(1[0-2]|0[1-9])` matches either:**

- a 1 followed by a digit between 0 through 2 (10..12)
- *or* a zero followed by a digit between 1 through 9 (01..09)

**The last one, `(3[01]|[0-2][1-9]|[12]0)`, matches either:**

- a 3 followed by 0 or 1 (30..31)
- *or* a digit between 0 and 2 followed by a digit between 1 and 9 (01..29)
- *or* 2 or 1 followed by a 0, since the rule above does not allow the number to end on zero (shutting out 00).

Comment: Thank you so much, and thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: No problem. Happy coding!

Comment: Could I also put brackets around the entire thing and add `|(0)` to allow the date or 0?

Comment: Yep. `(the-regex-from-above|0)`

Comment: Following what @Vikas-Kitawat mentioned, in the last part, in the full code, you made it 1-9 not 0-9. `(3[01]|[0-2][0-9])`

However, how could I stop 00?

Comment: @MattCowley I updated my answer to both take Vikas' and your considerations into account (allowing 10 and 20 but not 00)

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is a minor problem in Dencker's Answer to accomodate the dates 10 and 20th of the month.

```
(201[0-7]|200[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{3})(1[0-2]|0[1-9])(3[01]|[0-2][1-9]|[12][0])
```

** Unable to comment on the Dencker's Post (Need 50 reputation score to comment)

Comment: Dencker's breakdown covers it, but the actual full code is wrong oddly.